# How to install Python and Selenium wed driver without having access to the internet

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I need to install Python and Selenium webdriver on a PC that does not have access to the internet, and don't how to accomplished that.

Sofar, I managed to download Python onto a thumb drive and was able to install it on the PC. But when it comes to Selenium webdriver, I don't know what to do.

Please help.

Regards,
Kiet

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a virtual environment with all dependencies that you need and transfer the venv folder.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).